# abstract away same methods in 2 models for use in a rails rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rake task that calls the methods of a model in which i have defined some methods. However, I need to also run the rake task in a different database with the clone table. So I ended up creating a 2nd  model that inherits from establish connection for details of the other database. I am considering adding the same methods in model 1 to the 2nd model. But this is not very DRY at all. And I have a ton of operations I am doing in the rake task for the first model that I would like to also run for the 2nd model. How should I handle this design?

Comment: You can use observer in rails also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a module:

```
module M
  def foo
    :foo
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

class B
  include M
end

A.new.foo # :foo
B.new.foo # :foo
```

Answer (score 0):

> try using activesupport concern.
>
> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html